Conditional probability on an interval with independent continuous random variables
I am a bit puzzled by this question:

Let Y, X, Z be independent random variables.
X is a Bernoulli random variable with paramaeter 0.5.
Y follows a Uniform distribution on interval [0,1].
Z has probability distribution function $f_z(Z)= 
\begin{cases} 
\frac{24}{z^4} & \text{for } z > 2 \\
0 & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}$.
i) Compute $P(Z>3|Y<Z/2)$.
ii) Compute $E(\frac{Z}{(1+XY)^2}).$

What puzzles me is the independence of the variables and then the conditionality of the probability question. I tried to compute $P(Z>3|Y<Z/2)=P(Z>3)$ but was told it is wrong. How can the cumulative probability of $Z$ be conditioned on Y if these two variables are said to be independent?
How does one go about tackling this question? Does it involve the Law of Total Probability? If someone can point me to a chapter in an introductory textbook (say, Wackerly) that discusses this particular scenario, I'd welcome it. Straightforward transformation and conditional probability examples don't seem to help.

What is $Q$? What is $U$? What did you try? Is the question related to solving the two computational tasks or is it more general about which theorems can be used to compute?

Sorry for the massive typos in my question. I corrected the  random variable names. My attempt was to compute the probability regardless of the conditionality, but this was said to be wrong. I'm not sure what my next option is.

The events ${Z>3}$ and ${Y<Z/2}$ are not independent, that's where your approach went wrong. Hint: follow the definition of conditional probability.

But $Z$ is always greater than $2$ and $Y$ is uniform over $[0,1]$, so $Y<Z/2$ is a certain event i.e. $\Pr(Y<Z/2)=1$. So, $\Pr(Z>3|Y<Z/2)=\Pr(Z>3)$.

Draw / shade the regions of interest (e.g., $Y<Z/2$) in the $Z$ vs $Y$ coordinate system and it will be clear.

$Z$ is always greater than $2$ and $Y$ is uniform over $[0,1]$, so $Y<Z/2$ is a certain event i.e. $\Pr(Y<Z/2)=1$. So, $\Pr(Z>3|Y<Z/2)=\Pr(Z>3)$.
